# Flutter installation issues, can't load or find main class in PC

Tags: android, windows, flutter, mobile, installation

I am finding some issues installing Flutter.

Everything was fine, a week ago, but it wouldn't recognize my Android Studio. Later I downgraded the version, but I started to get problems with the Android Licenses. And every time I try to run the command flutter doctor --android license s I get the error couldn't find or load class in PC.

Can someone help me? I have uninstalled and installed the Android Studio many times but it's not working I also have added environment variables but nothing. [image]  [image: The Error],

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall everything, then I could complete the installation. I recommend installing a version before 4.1 of the android studio